# Icon to remain in 64 by 64 and don't resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added an image to the page

```
 <img src="@licImage.ThumbnailImageUrl" class="thumbnail" />
```

and it shows as **64 by 64** and stays that size even if I resize my page which is what I aactually want.

But then I added an icon the same way but it shows as too big.
If I add this CSS, it will fix the being larger issue BUT it makes it more responsive so the images start becoming too small on smaller screen sizes

```
.pdfIcon {
    /*margin: 0 auto 10px auto;*/
    max-width: 64px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But I don't want it to resize itself. I just want it to not be that big

Comment: If you want it always 64px then why not `width:64px` ???

Comment: oh thanks :)  I am new to CSS.  Hadn't thought of that. It worked.

Comment: how about adding min width and max-width as 64px?

Comment: No problem mate glad to help ... I guess you can delete this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your style use width to be fix as or if you want the image to be big to small as image resize use width:100% and max-width:64px

```
.pdfIcon {
    width:64px;
}
```